# How do I make my bots snipe get messages per server instead of getting all the servers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-3.7

Ok, so when I delete a message, then do the snipe command, it gets a message from a different server. So, I will delete **Hello**, then do the command, it will send me a recently deleted message from an entirely different server. How can I fix this? Any ideas?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


    snipe_message_content = None
    snipe_message_author = None
    snipe_message_id = None

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message):

        global snipe_message_content
        global snipe_message_author
        global snipe_message_id

        snipe_message_content = message.content
        snipe_message_author = message.author
        snipe_message_id = message.id
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

        if message.id == snipe_message_id:
            snipe_message_author = None
            snipe_message_content = None
            snipe_message_id = None


    @commands.command()
    async def snipe(self, message):
        if snipe_message_content==None:
            await message.channel.send("Theres nothing to snipe.")
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{snipe_message_content}")
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Asked by {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}", icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
            embed.set_author(name= f"{snipe_message_author}")
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed,delete_after=5)
            return


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Moderation(client))
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a wishlist, you want us to code the whole logic for you, it’s not a programming question at all.

Comment: Ah ok, I did not realize that thank you anyways.
@ŁukaszKwieciński , should I delete it?

Comment: You shouldn't delete a question if you're looking for an answer. Here on StackOverflow, even if the question you ask isn't as well-formulated, a lot of people will still try to help you with your programming problems.

Comment: And you can always edit your questions. It gives you more chance to get a meaningful answer ;)

Comment: Ok thanks!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionaries to store the messages deleted in each server. So I would recommend re-defining your current code to make it compatible with dictionaries.

Here is how I would define a simple "snipe" command:

```
class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self._last_member = None
        self.snipe_dict = {}
    
    # snipe
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message):
      if message.author.bot:
        return
      self.last_deleted = message.content
      self.deleted_author = message.author

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message):
        id = message.channel

        msg = str(message.content) + '˙' + str(message.author) + ''

        if message.attachments:
            r = str(message.attachments)
            p, thing = r.split('url=')
            thing, fdsdf = thing.split('>')

            msg = 'Sent an image. Not snipable.˙' + str(message.author) + ''

        self.snipe_dict[id] = msg

    @commands.command(name='snipe')
    async def sniped(self, ctx):
        id = ctx.message.channel
        wow = self.snipe_dict[id]
        if self.snipe_dict[id] == 'Pyth0nC0de':
            await ctx.send('There\'s nothing to snipe!')
        else:
            wow, message = wow.split('˙')
            embed = discord.Embed(title='Deleted Message', color=random.randint(100, 9999))
            embed.add_field(name=message, value=wow, inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            self.snipe_dict[id] = 'Pyth0nC0de'

            print(self.snipe_dict)
```

You should maybe rename the variables to more meaningful names, but the command itself works well.

Also note that if you restart the bot, the dictionary will reset to an empty one. If you want to save the snipped messages even after restarting the bot, you can use a database to store the data from the `self.sniped_dict` variable.

Comment: Wow ty! I agree with the variables being long... but they worked so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯


Worked!!! Tysm! My only idea for doing this was appending to a json over and over.... but that would have been very slow. Thanks!!!